# In a ruby project, what is a best practice for creating common internal library/framework?

Tags: ruby

I'm building a small framework to be used by several internal applications.  What is the best way to separate the framework and use it for other projects?

My initial thought was to create it as a gem, but it's only used internally.  Does it still make sense to create it as a gem to be used only internally?  If not, is there a best practice for a shared code location?

Comment: Private gems are a viable option. You can take a look at [Gemfury](http://www.gemfury.com/) for hosting them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably going to depend on use-case, but the gem structure is pretty standardized and is going to give you easy translation to other projects and new developers coming on. Beyond just simple and generic scripting, I always use a gem framework for internal utilities.

Check out [RubyGem-Bones](http://rubygems.org/gems/bones), it's a handy skeleton framework generator.

Comment: Where would you place your internal utilities to be shared with other applications?  Do you add this location to LOAD_PATH?  Is there a common practice for something like this?

Comment: Yeah you can add it to the LOAD_PATH and then require the specifics you need, or you can build the formal gem and install it making it fully accessible to any other ruby application under the same ruby library or rvm library.